# Synchronized blocks in constructors

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class with a static var like so

```
private static Object sMyStaticVar;
```

if i want to assign a value to this var in the constructor I have code like

```
if(sMyStaticVar == null) sMyStaticVar = new CustomObject(someRuntimeObject);
```

where `someRuntimeObject` is an object that is not available at the time my class is loaded and therefore prevents me from declaring my static var like the below

```
private static Object sMyStaticVar = new CustomObject(someRuntimeObject);
```

my question is, is the initialization of the static var object in the constructor thread safe? My instincts tell me its not and i should synchronise using the non-runtime class type as the lock, like the below

```
synchronized(MyClass.class)
{
    if(sMyStaticVar == null) sMyStaticVar = new CustomObject(someRuntimeObject);
}
```

(as opposed to the runTime type obtained from `getClass()`)

but as my instincts are usually wrong I would be grateful if anyone could shed some light on this for me!

Comment: (Mutable statics are a really bad idea.)

Comment: how so? in this case i am only create the object and assigning it to the static var anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If it is static, you should not assign it in the constructor. Make a static initializer method that does that `public static synchronized void initialize(someRuntimeObject)`.

Note the `synchronized` keyword: it is is the same as synchronizing on `MyClass.class`

Comment: and call that method from the constructor? Would this effectively be the same as my suggestion above but a little neater?

Comment: no, don't call it in the constructor. Call it from wherever you would call the constructor. The constructor is per-object, and your field is `static` (per-class).

Comment: are you saying i should call it at the same time the object is being created? Why would this not work if i called it from the contructor?

Comment: I do not want to have to call this init method before i create a new object of this kind every time.

Comment: @Dori as I noted, a `static` fields is per-class. It has no relation to a constructor. You shouldn't mix the two things. Either make it non-static and initialize it in constructor, or make it static and initialize it once

Comment: what if i dont want to create the object until the first time the class is instantiated?

Comment: The the _first_ time you initialize it with the static method, and instantiate an object. Each subsequent time you only instantiated it, without touching the static field

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4691/discussion-between-dori-and-bozho)

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the following is open to race conditions:

```
if(sMyStaticVar == null) sMyStaticVar = new CustomObject(someRuntimeObject);
```

Two threads could check `sMyStaticVar` at the same time, see `null`, create two objects, etc...

This means that you need synchronization. You could either synchronize on some existing object (there are multiple choices), or you could create an object just for the prurpose, so that you don't have to share the lock with anyone else, risking unnecessary contention:

```
private static Object sMyStaticVar;
private static Object sMyStaticVarLock = new Object();
```

Then, in the constructor:

```
synchronized(sMyStaticVarLock)
{
    if(sMyStaticVar == null) sMyStaticVar = new CustomObject(someRuntimeObject);
}
```

Comment: would syncing on the lock you describe above have any advantage over synchronized(MyClass.class)?

Comment: @Dori: If you don't know for sure who else might be synchronizing on `MyClass.class` and for what purpose, you can't know what sort of lock contention you're signing up for. Here, you know for sure that the lock is used for exactly one purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This syncrhonization is needed, but it's not enough to achieve thread safety.

You also need to ensure visibility of the field's value when you access it. So, you should either declare that field as `volatile` or add the same synchronization to every access of that field.