# Is it necessary to synchronize blocks in a constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor

This question does not answer the necessity part:
[Synchronized blocks in constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993874/synchronized-blocks-in-constructors).

Given this maxim

- JVM will not allow more than one thread to call the constructor of a class at a time

## Question A

Does it mean .... ?

1. JVM will not allow more than one thread to call any constructor of a class

   - such that even if there are more than one constructors in a class, a class can be instantiated by only one thread at a time.
2. If a class has more than one constructors, then each constructor can be called by no more than one thread at a time

   - such that if a class has three constructors, then three threads could simultaneously instantiate that class.

It seems logical to me that #1 is the answer to Question 1.

## Question B

If QuestionA.answer#1 is true, does it mean it is pointless to have synchronized blocks in a constructor?

For example, presuming setBrandAccessor method is called only by the constructor, is it unnecessary to synchronize the setBrandAccessor method? If necessary, please explain why.

```
class DataAccessor {
  static Brand brandAccesor;

  DataAccessor(Brand brand) {
    super(brand);
    setBrandAccessor(Brand brand);
  }
  
  private synchronized setBrandAccessor(Brand brand) {
    if (brandAccessor==null) brandAccessor=brand;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have this maxim from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> JVM will not allow more than one thread to call the constructor of a class at a time

This is not true, multiple threads can call constructors at the same time. I don't know where you got this maxim.

**Questions A**

Neither is true, the maxim itself is incorrect.

**Question B**

This does not do what you think it will do. `setBrandAccessor` would be synchronized on `this`, which is different for each constructor, so the method would not be synchronized in the way you expect it to be, and would de-facto be the same as not synchronizing it at all. You could do something like this:

```
class DataAccessor {
  static Object lock = new Object();
  static Brand brandAccesor;

  DataAccessor(Brand brand) {
    super(brand);
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (brandAccessor==null) brandAccessor=brand;
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
class DataAccessor {
  static Brand brandAccesor;

  DataAccessor(Brand brand) {
    super(brand);
    setBrandAccessor(Brand brand);
  }
  
  // Being static synchronized is the same as synchronizing on a static object
  private static synchronized setBrandAccessor(Brand brand) {
    if (brandAccessor==null) brandAccessor=brand;
  }
}
```

That does seem like a bit of an antipattern though. I'd be surprised if you can't structure your code better than this, but it's hard to comment without more context.

Comment: Instead of adding a lock object, simply make `setBrandAccessor()` static as well.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Added as an alternate answer

Answer (score 0):

Question A: Two threads can construct an object at the same time, running the constructor in parallel. What two threads can't do is construct the *same object* at the same time. The two threads will construct two different objects. The constructors run on two different objects, which removes one of the biggest needs for synchronized blocks.

Question B: synchronized blocks in constructors are not pointless: A constructor may access mutable shared state in other classes, or in static variables, and synchronized blocks are one way to guarantee mutual exclusion.

Regarding `setBrandAccessor` in (note that I have removed the static modifier, making the field an instance field):

```
class DataAccessor {
  Brand brandAccesor;

  DataAccessor(Brand brand) {
    super(brand);
    setBrandAccessor(brand);
  }
  
  private synchronized setBrandAccessor(Brand brand) {
    brandAccessor=brand;
  }
}
```

If you're using objects of this class from other threads, it may be necessary to make the method synchronized. You need to guarantee there's a "happens before" edge between the field being written and it being read in the other thread regardless whether the "write" happens in the constructor. Making the `get` and `set` methods synchronized guarantees proper multithreading visibility.

Another way to guarantee multithreading visibility is to remove the set method and making the field `final`.

```
  final Brand brandAccesor;

  DataAccessor(Brand brand) {
    super(brand);
    brandAccessor=brand;
  }
```